# Debian Squeeze - auto mounting USB/pen drive not working

Tags: usb, automount, debian-squeeze

On my Debian Squeeze laptop I am unable to auto mount pen drive or external hard drive. Here is the content of my `/etc/fstab`

```
#commented following line to just support vfat
#/dev/sdb1       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0   udf,vfat user,noauto     0       0
```

The problem is when I plugin a USB drive I see two icons for one USB drive. One is labled usb0 and other is the actual label of the pen drive for example `sandisk` or `kingston`. I can browse files in `usb0` but `sandisk`/`kingston` is not accessible. If I unmount the `usb0` I can access `sandisk`/`kingston` ladled folders and they are read/writeable by a normal user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this neat little howto](http://web.archive.org/web/20111026165327/http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=1402) based on udev. It mounts and unmounts a specified disk's partitions to known locations set up by you.

The part with the sample configuration is hard to read, so here it is again:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="57583", SYMLINK+="wd%n"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="57583", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /media/wd"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="57583", RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto -o defaults /dev/wd1 /media/wd", OPTIONS="last_rule"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="57583", RUN+="/bin/umount /media/wd"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="57583", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/wd", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Comment: late to accept but thanks for sharing the link. :-)